# Context Free Grammar, range of numbers

Tags: context-free-grammar

I have a homework assignment to write a context free grammar that matches the requirements specified in the language below.

[image: Context Free Grammer]

I've written this

[image: My solution]

But it looks like the same thing, I'm unsure if this is anywhere near correct.

Any feedback / suggestions are welcome. I'm very much confused as to how to write the "n >= 1" part.

Comment: Productions cannot be in the form you've provided. They have to be in the form `State -> State`, `State -> string` or `State -> string State string State string etc`. You want a production that looks like `E -> 0E11`. I'll leave it up to you to determine how that works and how to enforce `n >= 1`

Answer (score 0):

From the question and Welbog's comment, it looks like you're unclear on how grammars work. As you probably guessed, there's more to it than just writing down the same mathematical notation as in the problem statement. Here is a super-brief tutorial on how grammars work.

Grammars have terminal symbols and nonterminal symbols. Terminal symbols are symbols in the alphabet of the language while nonterminals are just made-up placeholders the grammar users. Nonterminals are related to strings of nonterminals and terminals by what are called productions. Productions describe what a nonterminal symbol (on the left) can be replaced with (on the right). Grammars have a start nonterminal symbol (often S) and they are said to generate or describe the language of strings that can be obtained by starting with the start nonterminal and successively applying productions to replace all nonterminal symbols with terminal symbols. For instance, here's a simple grammar for the language `a*b*`:

```
1) S -> AB        Nonterminals: S, A, B
2) A -> e         Terminals: a, b
3) A -> aA        Special: e is the empty string
4) B -> e
5) B -> bB
```

We see the string `aaabb` is in the language as follows:

```
   S         start nonterminal
-> AB        production (1): S -> AB
-> aAB       production (3): A -> aA
-> aaAB      production (3): A -> aA
-> aaaAB     production (3): A -> aA
-> aaaB      production (2): A -> e
-> aaabB     production (5): B -> bB
-> aaabbB    production (5): B -> bB
-> aaabb     production (4): B -> e
```

So in your case, we want to make a grammar that generates twice as many `1`s on the end as there are `0`s on the front, with all `0`s before `1`s. To do this, we need to make sure any production that adds `0` adds it at the front and adds exactly two `1`s at the back. Such a production is:

```
S -> 0S11
```

Now, with just this production, we can never get rid of `S`. We need to get rid of `S` by adding a production that replaces `S` with something that doesn't reference nonterminals. One option is the empty string `e`:

```
S -> 0S11
S -> e
```

However, we can see that this generates the empty string by the production `S -> e` which is not a string in the desired language (where `n >= 1`). Therefore, we must try another production. The shortest string in our language is `011`, so we can try

```
S -> 0S11
S -> 011
```

A moment's reflection should convince you that this is probably a grammar that generates the language we want.

Answer (score 0):

```
S->0S11|011
```

That's because for each 0 comes 2 1s, and the minimum (n>=1) is 011. 
So, it can be:

```
0S11
00S1111
000S111111
...
```

until you get the 011(to exit the loop):

```
000011111111
```